# $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is injective, {$a_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a real sequence. Prove convergence of {$a_{f(n)}$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help with the following task.
Let $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be injective and  {$a_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a real convergent sequence. Prove that {$a_{f(n)}$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to start. Maybe we should proof that the sequence is bounded? Since every convergent sequence is bounded....

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: Hint : Prove that $(f(n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: If it is bounded you can't conclude it converges... you can try to see if the definition is true but you have to know first what is the limit. Do you have some criterion for decrete the convergence?

Comment: You must also be assuming that $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges, right?  Otherwise taking $f$ to be the identity function gives a counterexample.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Yep you are right. an converges.

Comment: @Davide But every convergent sequence is bounded. And unbounded sequences are divergent....

Comment: But not every bounded sequence is convergent...

Comment: @Davide Yeah you are totally right...I see. Well is there any other option than proving that the sequence of f(n) tends to  infinity?

Answer (score 3):

Let $l\in \mathbb{R}$ be the limit of $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$. I am going to show that $\lbrace a_{f(n)}\rbrace$ also converges to $l$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = l$, there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for every $m\geq n_0$, we have that $|a_m - l|<\varepsilon$.

Now, since $f$ is injective, there exists $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, for every $p\geq n_1$, we have $f(p) \geq n_0$. This is true because the set of natural numbers $< n_0$ is finite, so there's only a finite set of numbers which are mapped by $f$ to a number $<n_0$ (by injectivity, there's at most $n_0 - 1$ of them), so you can choose $n_1$ to be the maximum of that finite set.

Now, for every $n \geq n_1$, we have $f(n) \geq n_0$, so $|a_{f(n)} - l|<\varepsilon$.